# Adding a new account on android restricted the number of contact fields

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

After running SampleSyncAdapter, a new account was created successfully and I was able to sync my contacts with the server but when I added a new contact it showed me only two fields i.e first name and last name. All the other fields were hidden. What changes do I have to make in the code to enable those fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding android:supportsUploading=”false” in sync-adapter xml file and it worked for me. Although it now lets me add contacts to phone only but not my account which is fine with me. If anyone has a better solution. it will be more helpful.